# JPA/Hibernate automatically create/validate database functions

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Is there any way to automatically create database functions using jpa/hibernate when i use `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create` ?

I've a number of custom functions (defined in a separated script file in the project) I use on my custom `@Query` in my repositories, but those functions needed to be create manually

You might think "what is the problem just run the script after created the database" but this must be done for every environment of the system: dev, test, prod... also it makes impossible to automatically test using in memory database (since when i hit run junit creates the database, hibernate creates the tables in the database, but nobody creates the functions so the repository wont work properly)

So how can I automatically create custom database functions using jpa/hibernate

Comment: Did you try any migration frameworks Flyway/Liquibase? Instead of using this spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create 
You can create scripts and put in the Migration directory, Flyway/Liquibase should be able to create in any environment along with your functions, custom types

Answer (score 1):

You can add an `import.sql` file in your classpath.
Hibernate will create the schema and then run it on the selected db.

[You can find more details in the documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#schema-generation).

Note though that the main purpose for schema generation in Hibernate is prototyping or testing.